# Count Number of Items of Specific Value and update field in another list

Tags: sharepoint-server, column

I am stumbling with this in a huge way and I'm hoping someone here can help. 
I have a SharePoint List that has two fields I want to collect data from. The first field in Location and the Second is Status.

I am looking for a way to show in possibly another list: 
Location Name - Number of Items Listed to that Location - Number of Items in Status 1 (specific to this location) , Number of Items in Status 2 (specific to this Location)

There are a number of different Locations but only 2 status options. I cannot use the excel webpart (not enabled in our company) to extract the data and show it that way so needing to find a workaround.
I hope all the above makes sense!

Thanks in advance to anyone that might be able to help!
Edited to add that I have created a list with the Area's and beside each I have a count related lookup field which gives me the total number of units - now I'm just looking for how to add the number of units in status 1 and status 2

Deirdre

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show items in group and count them by group, you could use Group By and Count in view setting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you. I had looked at that but was told by the person that wants it that it was too hard to figure out what number was what, the format they are looking for is like a data table with clear headings like this:    Area:      Total:      Status 1:     Status 2: and then the items listed below that.

Comment: You could use rest to filter items you want and then count them in code.Sample:/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test3')/items?$filter=(( Title eq 123) and (status eq 2))

Comment: Hi THank you for the suggestions but I managed to achieve this by using infopath and set the default value to count items in the other list that equalled the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for the suggestions but I managed to achieve this by using infopath and set the default value to count items in the other list that equalled the parameters